# if (count == 1) close this form and open form2, how?

Tags: c#

How do i make it if (count == 1) for it to do the same stuff it does at the moment, but instead of hiding, to close and open the other form (e.x form2)?

I've tried this.Close(); but it ended up closing the program before the code for opening the new form would run.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=dolfin;password=quack";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);

            MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from database1.logins where username='" + this.username_txt.Text + "' and password='" + this.password_txt.Text + "' ;", myConn);

            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myConn.Open();
            myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                    count = count + 1;

            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username and password is correct.");
                this.Hide();
                Form2 f2= new Form2();
                f2.ShowDialog();
        }
            else if (count > 1)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Username and Password... Access Denied!");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Username and password is not correct... please try again.");
            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Closing the main form will end its message loop, the code will break out from `Application.Run(yourMainForm);` You don't need to close your form, hiding it is enough, don't think it's a waste of memory, I think it's not worth mentioning here.

Comment: I need it to close tho, it's okay if the message doesn't show up.

Comment: That code is REALLY high vulnerable! Specially in a login! if in the password textebox I write "PASSWORD OR 1 = 1"  the username and password will be correct.

Comment: I guess this kind of code is taught in some schools as a start-up for any newbie.

Comment: I would use `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog` and close it after the show instead of before.

Answer (score 2):

You should be making a change like this in your `program.cs` file, because currently your first form is your applications main form; it cannot be closed without ending the application, but that's easy enough to change.

Instead of only creating one form and using that as the entire applications main form, create your login form, start a message loop for it, when it ends (namely, when the form is closed) you can look at a property that you have set for it (either the one I used, or a custom property) and based on that result, you can conditionally create a new form and start a whole new message loop for that form, where that second form is now the new main form:

```
Form1 first = new Form1();
Application.Run(first);
if (first.DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    Form2 second = new Form2();
    Application.Run(second);
}
```

Comment: Could i do a more easy thing? Like make it when you click the x button (close button) in form2, it to kill the application Code.exe in taskmanager? (for example)

Comment: @user3024598 This is pretty darn easy; it's just a few lines of code, and it does exactly what you want, and it's not really complex at all.  This is also a semantically appropriate way of approaching the problem.  Odds are high the alternative you'd try would just be harder to work with, not easier.